# Getting different elements from given data text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on Visual Studio about Python. Here my sample data:

```
00000110 Address complete
00001001 Answer
00000001 Blocking 39
```

I want to search spesific data be like "00000110"  and "00000001" in the data and output be like:

```
Address complete
Blocking 39
```

So, I use this code for finding result:

```
key1 = "00000110"
key2 = "00000001"
for line in f.readlines():
    if line.startswith(key1):
        print(line.lstrip(key1 + " "))
    elif line.startswith(key2):
        print(line.lstrip(key2 + " "))
```

However the output shows only second one which is:

```
Blocking 39
```

Is there any way to take both of result?

Comment: Try `if line.startswith(key1) or line.startswith(key2):` and remove the `elif`

Comment: First of all Thank you for answer @Bazingaa but I tried it, stills continue giving output only "Blocking 39"

Comment: That's weird, the code seems fine. Try adding some extra prints to see where it gets (e.g, add `print('GOT HERE')` inside the `if` blocks, print the current line, etc.

Comment: Could not reproduce - works fine for me.

Comment: Okay, I want to explain to you simple way my code but after a while I notice that it works fine @Baginzaa. I changed someof my code and It works. Thank you so much you safe my life :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not use the elif statement and use two if statements since nested ifs seems to execute only one in your case.Try below code:

```
key1 = "00000110"
key2 = "00000001"
for line in f.readlines():
    if line.startswith(key1):
        print(line.lstrip(key1 + " "))
    if line.startswith(key2):
        print(line.lstrip(key2 + " "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use a list called `keys` to identify the lines that we want.  Then we can use list comprehension to `join.()` the latter part of the line, and print those new lines.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    content = [(line.strip()).split() for line in f]

keys = ['00000110', '00000001']
lst = [' '.join(i[1:]) for i in content if i[0] in keys]

for i in lst:
    print(i)
# Address complete
# Blocking 39
```